# C# List start with value 1

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, indexing, int

When i use `for (int i = 1; ..)` skip the loop the first item.
How can i start with index 1 and dont skip any item?

```
private void buttonReadAndSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ReadFromFile rd = new ReadFromFile();
                var fileList = rd.readFromFile();
                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
                {

                    var item = (fileList[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    list.Add(item);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
                }
                buttonReadAndSort.Enabled = false;
            }
```

Comment: Why would you start with `1`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen ik wil met 1 beginnen zodat ik index kan vermenigvuldigen met een andere getal.

Comment: Why would you want to start at index 1 (so element #2), but not skip element #1? Should the element be processed at the end of the loop? If it should be processed in the beginning, then just start with index 0. If you need the index to be +1 for any other operation, just use the `var addedIndex = index + 1` variable or something like it... Very strange question if you ask me...

Comment: @id94 Based on your question/experience, you could do this: You'll create an extra variable that add 1 to the number. The answer Tim gave is correct. Everywhere you use `i`, use `i + 1` instead. See his second example.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want to start with index 1 but access the item at index 0:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= fileList.Count; i++)
{
    var item = fileList[i-1];
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    list.Add(item);
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

But you could also loop normally and add +1 where you need it 1 based:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
{
    var item = fileList[i];
    Console.WriteLine("item:{0} #{1}", item, i + 1);
    list.Add(item);
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: @id94 can you post a complete code snippet, and explain what result you want to achieve - and what's wrong with what you are getting now?

Answer (score 2):

List, like array, start at zero. Not sure why you would want it to start it at 1 and not skip any items. I do something like `csvLinesPartNumber.Add("stuff")` to add to the list and then I can get `"stuff"` from the particular index like so: `csvLinesPartNumber[4]`. For example, I am doing a `while sqlreader dot read` which will loop through the table with the particular ID. Then you can do another loop to get the data. Just make sure you put the index in the square brackets.

Comment: I have the same issue.  The easy (and obvious) workaround is Tim Schmelter's answer.  As to why you would want to do this, in my case I am loading data from an Excel spreadsheet (1 based row numbers) to a list and would like the subscripts to be the same.